# How much of a performance benefit using hyper-v vs virtualbox?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualbox, hyper-v, hypervisor

After reading up a bit on virtual machines and hypervisors I have a question:

I know there are two different types of hypervisors - type1 and type2. Type1 hypervisors seem to take out the need to run a virtual machine on top of an operating system. To me this would make them faster for development given that type1 hypervisors have direct access to the hardware instead of having to go through a host OS first. Wouldn't it be beneficial then, as a game developer and 3d modeler, to utilize something like window's hyper-v (which is a type1 hypervisor) over something like virtualbox (which is a type2)?

I ask because I know traditionally type1 hypervisors such as hyper-v are used more for server use instead of desktop use. I just want my virtual development environment to be as fast and responsive as possible.

Comment: AFAIK Type1 is always better... when you can. But Type1 is disabled by default on most machines, and not all support type1, wheras Type2 works anywhere.  I'm fuzzy on details though, so I hope someone can fill in the blanks in an answer.

Comment: Ya me to. I have windows 8 pro and I have the option to enable it but just waiting till I (hopefully) hear some responses.

Answer (score -1):

i think for application development you must used virtual box. for Hyper-V is prefer for cloud. Virtualization network, same as Virtual Cloud, Virtual OS, and anything used cloud system(they prefer used on Data). Hyper-V always lagging when i install Visual Studio too. Than used Virtualbox